# how to use no margin image side image in html, css

Tags: html, image, margin

I want to show this four images without any margin. How to do this?

Each A,B,C,D look like one image.

A
B
C
D

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="a.png">
    <br/>
    <img src="b.png">
    <br/>
    <img src="c.png">
    <br/>
    <img src="d.png">
</div>
```

I tried css margin=0 and style padding =0 but it is not working.

Update---

```
<img id="ImgEmotion" src="a.png" width="40" border="0">
<img src="b.png" width="20" height="20" border="0">
```

If I use css, I know there are no margin.

If I use `#no_margin`, how can I apply to img tag? Also I need the `'id='ImgEmotion'`.

Comment: I have created a fiddle. Have a look and let me know what's wrong with this..http://jsfiddle.net/jpHff/

Comment: Your exam are wrong. add width size to 4 images and run it.width=100

Comment: so you want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/jpHff/1/

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
img 
{
    margin:0; 
    display:block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div align="center">
    <img src="a.png">
    <img src="b.png">
    <img src="c.png">
    <img src="d.png">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SVdrq/)

Comment: Thanks to @TheEwook. But, I have another css "flote:left" on img. How to make and use it?
<img src="a.png" id="id"><img src="b.png">