# HTML5/Bootstrap formatting - images without padding/margins

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a block of 3 images, 2 are of the same size and 1 has double the width of the rest of them. I've searched here similar questions but they didn't work for me.

[how to use no margin image side image in html, css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048480/how-to-use-no-margin-image-side-image-in-html-css) <-- not working, tried another similar question too

HTML5 code is:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.blockUI.js"></script>    
</head>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="max-height: 450px; max-width: 1380px;margin:0;padding:0;"><!-- tried without margin/padding as well -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="margin:0;padding:0;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="margin:0;padding:0;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" style="margin:0;padding:0;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tried without margins/padding too with no results. I'm using Bootstrap 4 as base CSS, I currently have another CSS sheet i can edit if needed. It seems some CSS sheet is creating the margin after the other CSS is being applied but i can't seem to find it.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aO0a.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean? The gaps between images you saw are the paddings from the columns. If you don't want them, simply adding bootstrap class `.no-gutters` on the `.row` element, per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#no-gutters.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="images/2.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-fluid"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <img src="images/3.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/158414/

Comment: did'nt know the word gutters, seems my english still needs some improvement, this is working, thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't know it either :p